# Read the date in Linear Regression in python?

Tags: python, date, linear-regression

I face some unexpected error in my Linear Regression project, I want to read the information from the CSV file, but when I try to read the **Date** data, the error shows up.

this is my code :

```
# Load the dataset:
with open('covid_daily.csv') as f:
    data = csv.reader(f)
    for row in data:
        dataset.append(row)
```

```
for i in dataset:
    Date.append(i[0])
    Cases.append(i[1])
```

```
x = np.asarray(list(map(float, Date[1:]))).reshape(-1,1)
y = np.asarray(list(map(float, Cases[1:]))).reshape(-1,1)
```

**And this is the error**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-399021f65351> in <module>
----> 1 x = np.asarray(list(map(float, Date[1:]))).reshape(-1,1)
      2 y = np.asarray(list(map(float, Cases[1:]))).reshape(-1,1)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '7/13/2020'
```

how could i load the Date to Linear Regression ?

Comment: convert your date to epoch time

Comment: how can I do that and where exactly, can you learn me please, it's my first time in python